# Rails 4 ActiveAdmin XSS

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, xss, activeadmin

I have Rails app with ActiveAdmin.

I create some fields in show view:

```
row 'PHONE', :phone_number do
        organization.phone_number
      end
```

When I add this to field. Js run when I go to show view.

```
<script>alert("cookie: "+document.cookie)</script>
```

What can I do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
row 'PHONE', :phone_number do
  organization.phone_number.html_safe
end
```